# tkinter - check to see if a window is open

Tags: python, window, focus, tkinter

Just to warn all of you nice people: I'm relatively new to python and trying to write my first program.

My problem:
I got a main window (using tkinter) and a couple of other windows. Let's call them subWindow 1, 2 and 3
-> all with a menubar at the top, with a navigation tab to the other windows.

If the main window and subwindow 1 and 2, focus is on subwindow 2 and i use the menubar to navigate back to subwindow 1, it just opens a new instance of the window.

Question:
Is there a way to check:
if subwindow 1 is already open:
- Move subwindow 1 to the front (set focus to it)
else:
- Open a new instance of subwindow 1

Thanks in advance

---

Edit!
Thanks for the answer Christian Careaga, but focus_set() didn't work for me.
Got it working with a simple try/except though:

```
try:  
    root.deiconify()  
except:  
    openWindow()
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a way to tell if a window is running:

```
if 'normal' == root.state():
    print 'running'
```

`root.state()` gets the state of the window so if the window sate is normal it means its running

so in the main window you can use this condition to check if the if a subwindow is open
and if it is you can use `focus_set()` to bring that window to focus

Comment: Can we also know that if we have plotting option in tkinter window and we want to know that any matlotlib process is running or not but my matplotlib plot is not incoperated in tinter it's just called through a button which is there in my tkinter window